# Pass an URL parameter to public page and query by it (Oracle Apex)

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to call public apex page (without authentication) and pass parameter to it through the URL
and make the page to query a table with that parameter when page load

for example pass employee id through URL and the page display the employee data

if you have an example of dummy page it will be great

I am using Oracle Application Express 20.1.0.00.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for the emp table of one way to do this. I'm doing it with a report but you should be able to figure out based on this how do do it with a form too.

1. Create a page of type "Report > Interactive Report". Select table "EMP" and create the page.
2. Edit the page in page builder. In my case this the page nr is 15.
3. Create page item P15_ENAME of type "Hidden"
4. Modify the report region: set WHERE clause to `ENAME = :P15_ENAME`
5. Modify the page properties: set authentication to "Page is public". Save.
6. Run the page with the url like this <hostname_and_path>/f?p=<your_app_id>:15:::::P15_ENAME:KING (replace the values between <> with your own).

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I need it not as report because user need to update some fields
I did it the same way as you told me , no errors appears but query did not work as well

Comment: You're providing very little information about what you want to do exactly. "did not work as well" what does that mean ? It seems you want a form but that was not mentioned in the original post. If you create a page of type form on the emp table with primary key EMPNO then you can access that page just like in bullet point 6 - just replace P15_ENAME with P15_EMPNO and KING with 7839.

Comment: sorry if i did not mention that i need a form, not working means query did not retrieve any data

Comment: so did you try what I suggested in my last comment ? How did it go ? Best way to get help is to give as much info as possible.

Comment: sorry I am New in Apex World , how can i tell the form page to execute query 
it is always wait for data entry ,I need it to get the data depending on the passed parameter and let me update that record

Comment: Create a report and form. That generates 2 pages: a report and a form (create page > "report and form"). The link on the report to the form passes the primary key for the form - as an url parameter just like you want. Look at that url.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support (koen-lostrie)